# How to run raw_input in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I'm running the VSC on Mac with the latest OS.

The VSC just installed something called Pylint to the editor. 
I've changed task configuration for running Python using this code in *tasks.json*:

```
{

"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "python",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["${file}"],
"showOutput": "always"}
```

It works when I ran the following code to test it:

```
from random import randint
print(randint(1,25))
```

However, when I trying to run the `raw_input` on the task console:

```
nma = raw_input("What is your name?")
print "my name is %s" % nma
```

it shows nothing. In addition to that, I received some alerts from *pylint*:

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########
************* Module random number
2,0,convention,C0304:Final newline missing
1,0,convention,C0103:Invalid module name "random number"
1,0,convention,C0111:Missing module docstring
1,0,convention,C0103:Invalid constant name "nma"
```

No config file found, using default configuration
What am I suppose to do to run the `raw_input` function? And do I need to disable the *pylint*? If so, how?

Appreciate it!

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: @UrielEli I belive it's 2.7.13

Comment: where did you run this code? (console \ idle \ ide)

Comment: @UrielEli In Visual Studio Code, press `SHIFT`+`cmd`+`B`to run the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should know something about pylint.
 [Pylint wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint)

Pylint is a **source code, bug and quality checker** for the Python programming language.

If you want to run Python script and display output in VSC,try to 
`ext install python`
if you want to debug the Python code,check this.

[Visual Studio with Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python)

Hope this helps.